# Gitlab chef client failed

Tags: git, chef-infra, gitlab

When im running `gitlab-ctl reconfigure` command my chef client is getting failed. I made some changes in gitlab config file for making it run on https but now i reverted everything back still chef client is getting failed.

[image]

Can anyone help me and tell where i am making mistake.

Comment: From error, it seems gitlab['external_url'] value is not correct. Can you please share that.

Comment: thank you.
I missed ':' in external url. now it is working fine

Answer (score 1):

error was in external url line. just fixed that and it is working fine